# Flash and Firefox: can't click "Allow" on Privacy panel

Tags: apache-flex, flash, firefox, flex4

I've created a rather simple Flex application using Flex Builder 4, which connects to a webcam on the user's PC. To do so, Flash is presenting the user with the infamous privacy warning.

Now, the problem is that user can't click on the panel, as it seems unresponsive to any user interaction.

Some more details:

- Firefox 3.6.12 on Mac/OSX, Snow Leopard.
- Adobe Flash Plugin 10.1.85.3 / 10.1 r85
- The Flex app is working fine in its own window/tab but the problem shows up as soon as the html page with the Flex app is embedded into the iframe of another page.
- If I artificially put an Alert box before connecting the camera, the user is able to interact with the Flex application but as soon as the Privacy panel is shown, the Flex app stops interacting.
- The app works fine under Chrome and Safari but I have not tried this under Windows.
- I've read that there are problems with CSS positioning so I removed any CSS style impacting the Flex app.

Before I change my strategy and get rid of the iframe (which will cost me quite some effort) I'd be happy to know whether others have experienced the same problem and if there are workarounds.

Thanks.

Comment: Can be a flash player bug, have a look at http://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Are you running the debug player? I suspect you are hitting a security issue.

Comment: Well, I found many bug reports, both on Adobe and Firefox. Here are the the most significant: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-3750 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552520  https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4183 --- Too bad, it seems to be a major problem so I think I have to get rid of iframes to grant the widest usability.

Comment: did you put the swf to an iframe?? i can be done. my prog is in an iframe. and its call the function Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.DEFAULT) to show the privacy settings

Comment: Under Mac OSX (are you using Mac OSX?), my application consists of a form and an swf object underneath. Opening it in a page or in a tab is ok, but embedding it into another page using an iframe breaks the panel. That's not only me, I tried to bring up the settings panel for an embedded YouTube video (I used the new embedding method which exploits the iframe technology, as Vimeo does) and it gets unresponsive as well.

Comment: I find that this kinda thing also happens in Opera.

Comment: possible solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003724/cant-click-allow-button-in-flash-on-firefox

Comment: Well now it looks like with Lion upgrade this thing is not working anymore in all browser. I tried with camera dialog today on Lion and with Firefox, Chrome and Safari and the ALLOW button cant be pressed in any of them. Tried all purposed workaround but neither worked. I have flash in iFrame as well, but is working fine on Snow Leopard but not in Lion anymore! What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for weeks now. I found what may be the problem. It has something to do with the css alignment. try to remove the **text-align:center;** from the div flash is in and it will work again. Somehow the active areas from the security panel don´t shift with the display image…

Comment: These kinds of solutions only seem to work for very simple CSS webpages.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, this problem is apparently caused by an element containing the flash having the css `margin: 0 auto`. This leads to the left edge of the flash object sometimes being reported as a decimal, e.g. `$('.flash').position().left --> 450.5px`. Whenever it's not a whole number, the security panel failed to react to clicks.

The fix described in https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4183 and linked to by Christiano *almost* works. However, it failed whenever the browser was resized to be so small that the left margin disappeared.

Here's what fixed the issue for me:

```
function registerMozillaFlashFix() {
 if ($.browser.mozilla) {
   $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".flash").each(function(ii, e) {
        var $e = $(e);
        $e.css('margin-left', $e.position().left % 1 === 0 ? '0' : '0.5px');
      });
   });
 }
}
```

Then just call `window.resize()` once your flash has been set up.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.... also this bug is still around. Finally, adobe is terrible... they removed their JIRA and I had to manually search on bugbase. Actually the search was so terrible I had to search bugbase using google advanced search (first time I hate Adobe). For some reason both issues I found have been widthdrawn without solutions: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3328443 and https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2942091 . Google Search:  http://goo.gl/chJTiM