# flash allow button cannot be pressed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, macos, camera, osx-lion

I noticed this before. Sometimes in some browsers with flash camera dialog you won't be able to press **ALLOW** button to access camera, microphone. The issue is already exposed over here [Can't click allow button in flash on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003724/cant-click-allow-button-in-flash-on-firefox) and Adobe is tracking issue about this bug http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4656.

The purposed solution sometimes works but also not always. The other workaround I wound on web is to set the margin-left and margin-right CSS in flash container like this:

```
margin-left: 0.5px;
margin-right: auto;
```

Well now the **OS X Lion** came out and the damn thing doesn't work in any browser! I even tried the Facebook profile photo taker which also uses flash for taking photos. Also there you cant press ALLOW button. Same with YouTube video recorder etc...

What to do?

Comment: +1 - looking for workarounds too.  This is the fourth critical issue caused by Lion causing me pain in just 24 hours after release.  It must be the vendors like us at fault -but certainly not the mighty Apple, they dont have bugs or viruses. Thanks Jobs.

Comment: I would say it's more of a Adobe Flash Player bug then Apple's...? This bug is present for two years now and still exists. I would say Adobe could already address this and fix it million times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution works for today is adjust "Flash player General settings" for specific domain

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be fixed in Flash Player version 10.3.

Release notes:http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/901/cpsid_90194.html

Fixes in Flash Player 10.3 >> General >> "On Mac OS X Lion, the Flash Player Settings dialog box does not respond to mouse clicks (2918693)"

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/905/cpsid_90508.html#main_Flash_Player

Details:

> The Flash Player settings dialog does not respond to mouse clicks.
>   If you find yourself in this state, you can use the "tab" key to
>   change the focus to the "Close" button and use the spacebar to close
>   the dialog.  While not all settings are available, you can also use
>   the Flash Player native control panel located in System Preferences.

More or less we are going to have to wait for an update I think.

Comment: Yes this is one of the two available workarounds, but they do not help much. This is serious usability fail. I hope Adobe comes with the fix soon!