# Flash setting doesn't work on firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox

I have a problem with flash in Firefox. 
When the flash setting opens I can not click any button or link. 
I'm embedding the swfobject with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var params = {};
  params.wmode = "<?echo (strlen(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox')) > 0)?"direct":"transparent";?>";
  swfobject.embedSWF("record_swf", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",null,params,null);
</script>
```

I found some sources that say that maybe the error is related to container margins. I removed all css styles and didn't work. 
They also say that maybe is the wmode so I changed only for Firefox to "direct" and still  didn't work.

I don't know what else could I do. If there's any as3 library could help please let me know.

Source for both solutions: [Can't click allow button in flash on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003724/cant-click-allow-button-in-flash-on-firefox/13192906#13192906)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "window" or "opaque" wmode?

Comment: Yes, I just have changed to "opaque" mode and now only doesn't work in Mac. Thank you btw.